# when i connect to the server using telnet protocol ,I receive the error "could not open connection to the host,connection failed"

Tags: unix, telnet

when i connect to the specific server using telnet protocol ,I receive the error "could not open connection to the host,on port 23,connection failed" ..only I am unable to access specific three servers from telnet protocol..I am able to access some other servers without issues.

Answer (score 0):

This mean on those three servers telnet server is not started. You can check it by connecting to the host and execute command like:

```
netstat -an|grep 23
```